# Javafx - getting a node of scrollPane to front

Tags: javafx, scrollpane

I have two distinct main pane. These panes have a scrollPane and scrollPane has a another pane. I'm adding a node like a rectangle to ScrollPane's pane.

I want to get the rectangle in front of all.

I'm using toFront() method for rectangle. But rectangle does not get to front of scrollPane.

How can i get the rectangle in front of all, any ideas?

Comment: All three nodes have to be in the same group, your scrollPanes and the rectangle have to be siblings.

Comment: i'm adding more than one rectangle and then vertical scrollBar is displaying. So, rectangle's parent is pane and this pane's parent is scrollPane. When i scroll, i can display all rectangles. But when i move the rectangle, i want to display this rectangle in front of all, scrollPanei main Pane.   @KlausPrinoth